# How to find the difference on dates with time in string in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have 4 fields.
D1 in date format 29-JAN-19
T1 in varchar 18:18:52.98

D2 in date format 29-JAN-19
T2 in varchar 18:21:07.57

I want to find the difference from d2t2 - d1t1 in oracle. please help.

Comment: Honestly the best investment of your time right now would be to fix your table structure and use either timestamp or datetime columns, which contain both the date _and_ time in a single column.  You may get an answer here, but you should only view it as a temporary workaround until you can fix the bigger problem.

Comment: Concatenate date and time, use to_date and then use datediff

Comment: We dont have the privilege to fix the table structure. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the date into a string, concatenate it with the time and convert the result into a timestamp.
Do this for both fields and substract the result.

Something like this:

```
SELECT d1t1,
       d2t2,
       d1t1 - d2t2 AS date_diff
FROM
(
  SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(d1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || t1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF2') AS d1t1,
         to_timestamp(to_char(d2, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || t2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF2') AS d2t2,
  FROM   my_table
)
```